# How to integrate to get sinh? (Wolfram Alpha)

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, indefinite-integrals, wolfram-alpha

I am currently trying to find the curve that a surfer makes in attempting to get to beyond where the waves break while a current pushes against him perpendicularly, and am using this post as help: [Name that curve!](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/156334/name-that-curve)

I've gotten to a certain point but Wolfram Alpha doesn't explain the steps well, and I'm stuck.

I'm trying to go from this differential equation

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} = \frac{y - \rho r}{x},\quad r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$

to this equation for $y$:

$$y(x) = x \sinh(\sinh^{-1}(y_0) - \rho \log x)$$
WolframAlpha succeeds in getting from the first to the second but I don't understand how it integrates the left side at one point, and where the $\sinh$ comes from...

---

### WolframAlpha's approach

> **Step 1:** *Solve $\displaystyle \frac{\mathrm{d}y(x)}{\mathrm{d}x} = \frac{- \rho \sqrt{x^2 + (y(x))^2} + y(x)}{x}$, such that $y(1) = y_0$:*
>
> **Step 2:** *Let $y(x) = x v(x)$, which gives $\displaystyle \frac{\mathrm{d}y(x)}{\mathrm{d}x} = x \: \frac{\mathrm{d}v(x)}{\mathrm{d}x} + v(x)$:*
> $$x \: \frac{\mathrm{d}v(x)}{\mathrm{d}x} + v(x) = \frac{- \rho \sqrt{x^2 + x^2 (v(x))^2} + x \hspace{0.25mm} v(x)}{x}$$
>
> **Step 3:** *Simplify:*
> $$x \hspace{0.5mm} \frac{\mathrm{d}v(x)}{\mathrm{d}x} + v(x) = -\rho \sqrt{(v(x))^2 + 1} + v(x)$$
>
> **Step 4:** *Solve for $\displaystyle \frac{\mathrm{d}v(x)}{\mathrm{d}x}:$*
> $$ \frac{\mathrm{d}v(x)}{\mathrm{d}x} = -\frac{\rho \sqrt{(v(x))^2 + 1}}{x} $$
>
> **Step 5:** *Divide both sides by $\sqrt{(v(x))^2 + 1}$:*
> $$ \frac{\frac{\mathrm{d}v(x)}{\mathrm{d}x}}{\sqrt{(v(x))^2 + 1}} = - \frac{\rho}{x} $$
>
> **Step 6** *Integrate both sides with respect to $x$:*
> $$ {\int} \frac{\frac{\mathrm{d}v(x)}{\mathrm{d}x}}{\sqrt{(v(x))^2 + 1}} \mathrm{d}x = \int - \frac{\rho}{x} \mathrm{d}x $$
>
> **Step 7:** *Evaluate the integrals:*
> $$\sinh^{-1}(v(x)) = - \rho \log(x) + c_1,$$ *where $c_1$ is an arbitrary constant*.
>
> **Step 8:** *Solve for $v(x)$:*
> $$v(x) = -\sinh(\rho \log(x) - c_1).$$
>
> **Step 9:** *Simplify the arbitrary constants:*
> $$v(x) = -\sinh(\rho \log(x) + c_1)$$
>
> **Step 10:** *Substitute back for $y(x) = x \hspace{0.25mm} v(x)$:*
> $$y(x) = -x \sinh(\rho \log(x) + c_1)$$
>
> **Step 11:** *Solve for $c_1$ using the initial conditions:*
>
> *Substitute $y(1) = y_0$ into $y(x) = -x \sinh(\rho \log(x) + c_1):$*
> $$-\sinh(c_1) = y_0$$
>
> **Step 12:** *Solve the equation:* $c_1 = -\sinh^{-1}(y_0)$
>
> **Step 13:** *Substitute $c_1 = -\sinh^{-1}(y_0)$ into $y(x) = -x \sinh(\rho \log(x) + c_1)$:*
>
> **Answer:**
> $$\boxed{y(x) = x \sinh(\sinh^{-1}(y_0) - \rho \log x)}$$

I understand steps 1-5, but I don't understand how to continue from Step 6. Steps 7-11 seem to just randomly come out.

If someone can explain in a more human friendly way than Wolfram Alpha what is going on here I would be extremely appreciative...

Thank you!

Comment: You should avoid adding so many links in your question. You are expected to type everything yourself using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: The links on the questions should be only complementary. The questions are expected to be self-contained.

Comment: @Nightytime Thank you so much for the help editing...

Comment: It might be helpful to check that the derivative of $\sinh$ is $1/\sqrt{x^2+1}$.

Comment: @William Yes indeed that is part of the solution but I don't understand what we do with the dv(x)/dx inside the integral, I've never come across having to integrate a derivative which is multiplied by some other term

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially this is the substitution rule. More formally, the substitution $V=v(x')$ yields
$$\int_0^{x}\frac{dv/dx'}{\sqrt{1+v(x')^2}}\,dx'=\int_0^{v(x)}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+V^2}}dV$$
where I've switched to definite integration to make sure the changes of variable are all clear. Since $$\frac{d}{dV}\sinh^{-1} V=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+V^2}},$$ this integrates to $ \Big[\sinh^{-1}V\Big]_{V=0}^{v(x)}=\sinh^{-1} v(x).$ In solutions, the above definite is instead typically presented as the indefinite integral
$$\int \frac{dv/dx}{\sqrt{1+v(x)^2}}dx=\int\frac{dv}{\sqrt{1+v^2}}=\sinh^{-1}v(x)+C$$ which is what WolframAlpha has done.

Comment: Is it acceptable (i.e. mathematically rigorous) to do the following: In the first line that you have written, (Step 7 of WolframAlpha), instead of dividing dv(x)/dx by the term in the square root, could we just multiply it by 1 over that term, and then because the dx will now be in the denominator and the dx is added on the right, can they just be cancelled leaving the integral in terms of dv only, as you have done in your last line? Otherwise, I'm a bit confused as to why you have written v(x'); what does dx' means and so forth? Thanks.

Comment: Also, is this differential equation homogenous then? When Wolfram substitutes y(x) = x*u(x) this reminds me of the method to solving homogenous diff. equations. In that case, what do you make of @Sebastiano's solution? He says the equation is linear but that isn't the case when we write r out as the sqrt(x^2+y^2) in which case we cannot put the equation in the standard linear form. WolframAlpha also says its non-linear.

Comment: Forget my earlier comments, could you just explain why you've written x' everywhere instead of x? Why would we need to take the derivative of x everywhere?

Comment: $x’$ isn’t a derivative but a dummy variable of integration (since $\int_0^x f(x)\, dx$ is not a meaningful expression). It’s such a common convention in my area (physics) that I wasn’t thinking about the other meaning.

Answer (score 0):

I should add that step $(9)$ is useless, in the sense that WolframAlpha first changed the $+c_1$ to $-c_1$ in the previous step without mention, to then make it a separate step to change it back. Semiclassical explained step $(7)$ perfectly in my opinion, and apart from the weird intermediate step changing the sign, I think the rest should be clear?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, yes indeed step 9 does not seem to have much purpose. Since the others aren't answering, would you mind looking at @Sebastiano's answer? I don't see whether the equation is linear or not. I guess it is if we keep r as it is but if we replace r by the square root term it becomes homogenous?

Comment: I was just adding a comment under his response since he had a mistake somewhere, but I guess he deleted it while I was editing my comment?

Comment: Yeah it seems so. Except the mistake you found, would you have said his method works? (i.e. is it a valid method)