# Any ideas on how to add complexity?

Tags: trigonometry, graphing-functions, curves, hyperbolic-functions

I am investigating the path of a surfer who, starting at a point on the shore, is trying to paddle to a certain point directly in front of him (perpendicularly to the shore) while a current pushes perpendicularly on him. I have found the equation of the path he will take, which is in fact the same as is answered to the following question: [Name that curve!](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/156334/name-that-curve)
It is a curve that looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DV47W.png) and here is its equation:

$y(x) = x\sinh(\sinh^{-1}(y_0)+k\ln(x))$

Now I was wondering whether I could somehow take into account the waves periodically crashing on the surfer. Instead of going in a smooth path, he would follow a similar route except every couple meters get pushed backwards.
Any idea how I could mathematically show this, would I incorporate some sine function to make it cyclical?

I would greatly appreciate any ideas and feedback.